# Cannot show data from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to implement a chat with PHP, I don't have problems inserting values on my database
but when I try to get messages and name to show them it gets a lot of "undefines" in message and date box.

```
require_once"../connection/config.php";

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $result = [];
    $message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;

    if(!empty($message) && !empty($name)){
        $new_message = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `chat`(`message`,`name`) VALUES (:message,:name)" );
        $new_message->bindParam(':message',$message,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $new_message->bindParam(':name',$name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $new_message->execute();

        $id=$con->lastInsertId();
        $_SESSION['id']=(int)$id;
        $return_array['redirect']= ''; 
        $return_array['is_login']= true;
    }
    $start = isset($_GET['start']) ? intval($_GET['start']) : 0 ;
    $items = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `id` > :start");
    $items->bindParam(':start',$start,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $items->execute();

    while($row = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)){
        $result['items'][] = $row;
    }

    header('Acces-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Also I tried to show using traditional way to connect with database (it works perfectly), but I know using PDO is more secure, so I tried this.

This is what I have on JavaScript

```
var name = null,start = 0,url="http://localhost:8077/know.ncn.pe/validations/validate_chat.php";
    $(document).ready(function(){
      name = prompt("Enter your name");
      load();
      $('form').submit(function(e){
        $.post(url,{
          message:$("#message").val(),
          name:name
        });
        $("#message").val("")
        return false;
      })
    });
    function load(){
      $.get(url + "?start="+start,function(result){
        if(result.items){
          result.items.forEach(item =>{
            start = item.id;
            $("#messages").append(renderMessage(item));
          });
          $("#messages").animate({scrollTop:$("#messages")[0].scrollHeight});
        };
        load();
      });
    }
    function renderMessage(item){
      let time = new Date(item.created_on);
      time = `${time.getDate()}/${time.getMonth()}/${time.getFullYear()}, ${time.getHours()}:${time.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0':''}${time.getMinutes()}`;
return `<div class="msg"><p>${item.name}</p>${item.message}<span>${time}</span></div>`
    }
```

[image: undefined]

Comment: "Using PDO" is not more secure. I don't know what you are comparing it too, but you can write extremely bad code using PDO too. PDO doesn't offer any inherent security over other extensions

Comment: well i've heard about it prevents sql injections

Comment: No. PDO does not prevent SQL injections, but it does offer prepared statements like most extensions. Using prepared statements you can avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

I thing that's probably your `$new_message` request. What I suggest you is to write it like that:

```
$new_message = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO chat(message, name) VALUES (:message,:name)" );
```

I don't know why you do this:

```
`chat`(`message`,`name`)
```

Your request should not have `...`

Comment: I think no matter if i use ` or not because `INSERT` works, the problem is when i try to get data from database in `SELECT`

Comment: Are you talking about backticks or did you actually mean `...`?

Comment: I was talking about this  : `

Comment: `$items = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > :start");` this is why i suggest without using the `